# Writing into SAS log

Tags: sas

I know I can use `%PUT` to write a text string in the log window, but what if I want to write in the log the result of a function, for example `PROBNORM(x)`? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you using base SAS, or SAS/IML (`proc iml;`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `%sysfunc()` to evaluate a function during macro resolution.

IE

```
%let x=1;
%put %sysfunc(probnorm(&x));
```

Answer (score 4):

In the data step, PUT and PUTLOG functions will write to the log using data step variables.  You can't use a function directly, but if you assign the value to a variable you can write that variable.

```
data _null_;
 x=1;
 y = probnorm(x);
 put "Probnorm is " y=;
run;
```

While you can do so using %PUT and %SYSFUNC, they have a significant limitation in that they cannot access data step variables (without a lot of work anyway).